# WPF content overriding

Tags: c#, wpf

I am learning WPF.  For example i want to draw circle. I can something like:

```
 private const ushort _operatorRadius = 50;
 public MainWindow()
        {
            var _canvas = new Canvas();
            var _operatorEllipse = new Ellipse();
            SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();

            // Describes the brush's color using RGB values.  
            // Each value has a range of 0-255.
            mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 0);
            _operatorEllipse.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;
            _operatorEllipse.StrokeThickness = 1;
            _operatorEllipse.Stroke = Brushes.Black;

            // Set the width and height of the Ellipse.
            _operatorEllipse.Width = _operatorRadius;
            _operatorEllipse.Height = _operatorRadius;
            _canvas.Children.Add(curOperElips);
            this.Content = _canvas;
}
```

But this.Content = _canvas; will override content of windows and then i can't use visual editor and MainWindow.xaml. How to combine them?

Comment: Not too sure what you're asking; you can use XAML instead of code to do drawing; and whilst your window can only have one content, you can make that content a container like grid, stackpanel, dockpanel; and then they can host many items or more containers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add multiple children to your window then you should add a `layout container` like `stackpanel, grid` etc to it and then add children to these containers.

In this example if you want some section of your window to have this `Canvas` then you should add a `ContentControl` in your window and then set its `Content` to the `Canvas`

```
  <StackPanel>
    <ContentControl x:Name="myContent"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

and in code behind:

```
this.myContent.Content = _canvas;
```

In this way only your contentcontrol will update